# Kubernetes - monitor number requests

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an app running on Google Container Engine.

I would like to monitor number requests per second my api is receiving
how can I do this?

is there a way monitoring from historical metrics on [Stackdriver](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/12/monitoring-Container-Engine-with-Google-Cloud-Monitoring.html)
as I am opted for [Stackdriver Premium](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/ I see that Stackdriver is deployed in the cluster by default. It looks like that, according to https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics, this includes the metrics you are looking for.